# Horizontal sliding menu inside android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, slidingmenu

I'm making an app for a restaurant in Android Studio. I have a MainActivity with a Navigation Drawer and I change between different Fragments so I can keep the Navigation Menu the same but switch content.

So, I want to add a horizontal menu bar on the top side of one of those Fragments, so users can filter different type of dishes (dessert, meat, fish, pasta ...). The fragment also has a ListView to show the dishes taken from a DB

Here is the question, what's the best approach I can take to keep it as simple as possible? I thought of adding a LinearLayout with buttons to the Fragment's layout but since I have several of them they are too small, so a sliding bar would be nice but I have no idea how to start with it.

Thanks for reading, I'll keep looking

-- EDIT --
Here is the code I'm refering to

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {

static AdaptadorMenu adaptador;
static ArrayList<ElementoMenu> arrayList = new ArrayList();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

    //((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment Inbox");

    cargaDatos();
    //consultaBD();

    return view;
}

private void cargaDatos(){
    JSONArray jsonArray = MainActivity.jsonMenu;
    arrayList.clear();
    if (jsonArray!= null) {

        JSONObject jo;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int idPromocion = Integer.parseInt(jo.getString("idMenu")); //en mysql id empieza por 1, por eso el -1 abajo
                String nombre = jo.getString("nombre");
                String descripcion = jo.getString("descripcion");
                float precio = Float.parseFloat(""+jo.getDouble("precio"));
                String direcImagen = jo.getString("direcImagen");
                //Log.e("JSON", idPromocion + " " + nombre + " " + descripcion + " " + precio + " " + direcImagen);
                arrayList.add(new ElementoMenu(idPromocion-1, nombre, descripcion, precio, direcImagen));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        aplicaAdaptador();
    }
}

public void aplicaAdaptador(){
    adaptador = new AdaptadorMenu(getActivity(), arrayList);
    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListAdapter(adaptador);
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
ActionBar actionBar;
private final int MENU = 0, PROMOCIONES = 1, MAPA = 2, RESERVAS = 3;
public static JSONArray jsonDatos, jsonMenu, jsonPromociones;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    if (navigationView != null) {
        setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);
    }

    setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);

    consultaBD();

    //setUltimaActualizacion(DateTime.now().toString());
    //Log.e("HORA", ""+getHoraActual()/1000);
    //getPreferencias(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    onResumeConsultaBD();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onResume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//aqui se elige que sucedera cuando se pulse cada uno de los componentes del NavigationDrawer menu
private void setupNavigationDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.item_carta:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            setFragment(MENU);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CARTAPULSADA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.item_promociones:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            setFragment(PROMOCIONES);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "PROMOSPULSADA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.item_como_llegar:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            setFragment(MAPA);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MAPAPULSADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.item_reservas:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            setFragment(RESERVAS);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "RESERVASPULSADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.item_noticias:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            //setFragment(4);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NOTICIASPULSADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.item_sobre_nosotros:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            //setFragment(5);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SOBRENOSOTROSPULSADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

//aqui se llama a los fragments. MenuFragment, PromocionesFragment, MapFragment....
public void setFragment(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case MENU:
            cambiaFragment(new MenuFragment());
            break;

        case PROMOCIONES:
            cambiaFragment(new PromocionesFragment());
            break;

        case MAPA:
            cambiaFragment(new MapFragment());
            break;

        case RESERVAS:
            cambiaFragment(new ReservasFragment());
            break;

    }
}

private void cambiaFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Fragment's layout is just a RelativeLayout with a ListView in it

Comment: Can you post your code what you have done till now

Comment: Code added! Just found this tutorial that kinda makes the effect I'm looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PAsR5sIi6E

Comment: You can use horizontalScrollView to your buttons and on button click filter the adapter of your listView.

Comment: Why do you want horizontal bar? for showing filter option?

Comment: Ye, i get data from a XAMPP database with JSON and I have different types of dishes I want to apply a filter to. I'll try to use the HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Using HorizontalScrollView element was exactly what I was looking for, didn't knew android had that. In this tutorial is easily done https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PAsR5sIi6E

Thanks for answering, I should have looked a little more (Brain stops working after several hours :p)